# Not able to deploy keyclock quickstart example war in wildfly

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I can't reproduce the [tutorial](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-jee-vanilla) to deploy this application on wildfly.

I downloaded the wildfly and started wildfly-19.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh

And when I execute from project directory `mvn clean wildfly:deploy` I get this error

```
15:12:55,016 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war
    at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-client
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:299)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:283)
    at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:93)
    ... 8 more

15:12:55,021 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app-authz-jee-vanilla.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-client"}}
15:12:55,022 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "app-authz-jee-vanilla.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.app-authz-jee-vanilla.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-client"}}
15:12:55,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment app-authz-jee-vanilla.war (runtime-name: app-authz-jee-vanilla.war) in 11ms
```

I tried running on docker wildfly and other example applications and worked. I don't have any experience in java. What can I do to have this app up and running?

Comment: Did you install keycloak in WildFly?

Comment: Faced the same issue. keycloak standalone (bundled together with Wildfly) was the wildfly I have used. I didn't find the jar file and the module.xml relevant to org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-client in Wildfly modules or the quickstart war. So this could be a missing module in keycloak-10.0.1

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I don't think so, I just followed the tutorial I mentioned... How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Chamil where do I find it?

Comment: You'll want to look at the Keycloak documentation https://www.keycloak.org/. You definitely need to install Keycloak before it will work.

Answer (score 1):

With the command wildfly-19.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh, you are running keycloak on Wildfly.

Please use a different Wildfly server to host your servlet application. To communicate with the Keycloak running on the other server, you need "Keycloak OpenID Connect Client Adapter" installed into your Wildfly server which runs the servlet application.

You may use this [guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#jboss-eap-wildfly-adapter) to install the keycloak adapter into the wildly server. After you install this adapter into the new Wildfly, org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-client module will be available on this Wildfly.

However still there is a [blocker](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13690) for the latest java version [above java 11].

Comment: I accomplished the tutorial, now I think I have a Wildfly server hosting the application. I even did a ```mvn clean wildfly:deploy``` on the project(that was prompted the error on the question) with the credentials I setup in the guide you mentioned, and worked...
But I can't start the wildfly-19.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh, because gives port conflict, how can I change these ports? I need to start the keycloak server and configure the realms and clients...

Comment: Actually I managed to change the ```port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:1}"``` in /wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
But how can I access KeyCloak management? To set the realms and clients...

Comment: The default keycloak installation runs on the other wildfly server which is running on http://localhost:8080.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear. I just need to test this [quickstart project](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-jee-vanilla)
There they say I need a "WildFly 10 running"... I currently I have 2 widfly running, one in :8080 and the other in :8081... I'm so confused..
I followed the guide you mentioned, and ended up with a Wildfly server running as a service in my linux.

Comment: In the [guide](https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/install-keycloak-openid-connect-client-adapter-on-wildfly-on-ubuntu-18-04-ef98a99fc528), they say they'll use "Wildfly 16.0.0.Final", then I went to the other [article](https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/install-jboss-wildfly-on-ubuntu-18-04-ac00719a2f02), that it's mentioned to do so, and installed it, the result was the Wildfly running as a linux service.
When I started the /wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml I needed to do the trick of the port offset I said, that's ok until now.

Comment: But where is the Keycloak admin console? I still couldn't find it to configure the realms, clients and roles... 
If I start ./keycloak-10.0.1/bin/standalone.sh I can access the admin console...
Besides, when I access http://localhost:8080/app-authz-vanilla I get redirected to KeyCloak login page: 
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hello-world-authz/protocol
which is right, but I get a 404... What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/latest/docs/getting-started.md

Please refer this URL. It will explain the entire scenario.

Comment: I've read this documentation, and by the end of the day it still didn't work... I have KeyCloak running on Wildfly ```/keycloak-10.0.1/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100```
I have Wildfly running ```wildfly-19.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh```. 
The keycloak adapter seems to be available in Wildfly at ```wildfly-19.1.0.Final/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak```
The quickstart application seems to be deployed but when I access I get the following error [link](https://gist.github.com/brunobck/b8902627be5736627f4ec07586efe0e3)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the WildFly not started 100% successfully. In the 'standalone.xml' file's end, there are some ports which maybe not available to you. Check for the logs, disable/move conflicting ports.